# How to get over Android CompanionDataManager using deprecated methods?

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

In its own documentation page, it is stated that **CompanionDeviceManager** is the preferred mechanism in order to scan for devices without asking for the infamous FINE_LOCATION premission.

```java
deviceManager.associate(pairingRequest, new CompanionDeviceManager.Callback() {
    executor,
    // Called when a device is found. Launch the IntentSender so the user can
    // select the device they want to pair with.
    @Override
    public void onDeviceFound(IntentSender chooserLauncher) {
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(
                    chooserLauncher, SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0
            );
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Failed to send intent");
        }
    }
```

This code has unfortunately various issues. For starters, it does not compile out of the box, since you have to move the `executor`argument. But also, even when it was written, it makes use of **a huge lot** of deprecated methods.

The first deprecated method is found in `onAssociationPending()`: `startIntentSenderForResult`. The docs have put a lot of effort over a long time to discredit this mechanism. So then I converted the code to:

```java
LAUNCH_DEVICE_CHOOSER_ASSOCIATION.launch( chooserLauncher );
```

And its counterpart:

```java
private final ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSender> LAUNCH_DEVICE_CHOOSER_ASSOCIATION =
            this.registerForActivityResult(
                    new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
                    result -> {
                        if ( result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK ) {
                            final BluetoothDevice DEVICE =
                                    result.getData().getParcelableExtra( CompanionDeviceManager.EXTRA_DEVICE );
                            if ( DEVICE != null ) {
                                this.onDeviceFound( DEVICE );
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

There are various problems with this code, though:

- The compiler complains about an `ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderResquest>` being provided, instead of an `ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSender>`. I don't understand why. If I change `ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSender>` to `ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest>`, then it compiles, but then the method `launch()` complains about passing an `IntentSender` when an `IntentSenderRequest` was expected.
- in the code immediately above, `result.getData()` returns an `Intent`. This class is expected to have a `getParcelableExtra()` method which is... deprecated. But that is not all, the parameter to that method should be `CompanionDeviceManager.EXTRA_DEVICE`, which is, you guessed it, deprecated. In the latter's documentation it is adviced to use `AssociationInfo::getAssociatedDevice`, method which is produced out of the blue. I mean, there is nowhere to be found (at least I was unable to find it), how to get to an object of that class.

My questions are:

- How is this code converted to the (supposedly) newer/cleaner/safer `registerForActivityResult` mechanism?
- How can I get the extra info from the `ActivityResult` object, avoiding deprecated mechanisms?
- Even better, I should obtain an `AssociationInfo` object, to which I should call `getAssociatedDevice()` from which I should obtain an `ScanResult` object, since I am filtering for BLE devices. How can I get that from `result.getData()` (an `Ìntent`)?

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: The transformation to registerForActivityResult is usually straightforward, change the code in onActivityResult to a lambda, be sure to declare this function since the creation of the activity .

The extra will be the parameter in the lambda

Comment: Yep, it is usually straightforward.